# Powershell - Add a key in a specific manner to a JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

i have an array converted to a json (`$user_data_JSON = $user_data | ConvertTo-Json`) in powershell which looks like this

```
$user_data_JSON
{
  [
    {
        "targetId":  "5007Y00000K5nkjQAB",
        "login":  "login1",
        "password":  "scRHDztkKbO"
    },
    {
        "targetId":  "5007Y00000MNbDvQAL",
        "login":  "login2",
        "password":  "scRHDztkKbO"
    }
  ]
}
```

But i need to modify it like this with a KEY value on top:

```
$user_data_JSON
{
    "logins":[
        {
            "targetId":  "5007Y00000K5nkjQAB",
            "login":  "login1",
            "password":  "scRHDztkKbO"
        },
        {
            "targetId":  "5007Y00000MNbDvQAL",
            "login":  "login2",
            "password":  "scRHDztkKbO"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I manage to achieve this?
I've already tried to create a new array object, add the key and convert it to a json file like this:

```
$jsonBase = @{}
$list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$list.Add("Foo")
$list.Add("Bar")
$jsonBase.Add("Data",$list)
$jsonBase | ConvertTo-Json
To get something like this:
{
  "Data": [
    "Foo",
    "Bar"
  ]
}
```

but when I convert my array to a json again, it looks kind of trunkated:

```
$jsonBase | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
{
    "logins":  [
                   "[\r\n    {\r\n        \"targetId\":  \"5007Y00000K5nkjQAB\",\r\n        \"login\":  \"login1\",\r\n        \"password\":  \"scRHDztkKbO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n   
     \"targetId\":  \"5007Y00000MNbDvQAL\",\r\n        \"login\":  \"login2\",\r\n        \"password\":  \"scRHDztkKbO\"\r\n    },"
               ]
}
```

How can I get a propoer JSON object?
Thanks

Comment: The first JSON sample is _not_ valid JSON (`[...]` nested directly in root object). Are you 100% sure this is what `ConvertTo-Json` outputs?

Comment: Actually this was more of an example, but the initial format is correct. JSON files are like { [{aaa:bbb},{ddd:eee},..,{xxx:yyy}] }. The variable is correctly defined. I just tested the solution of mkelement0 with my exemple and it worked fine with the process i needed to do with JSON files afterwards. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the *JSON* (text) representation of your array (`$user_data_JSON`), use its original, object form (`$user_data`) to construct a wrapper object with the desired top-level property:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ logins = $user_data } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

If you use a preexisting JSON string as the value of property to be converted to JSON with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json), it is treated like any other *string* value, resulting in the representation you saw, with `"` characters escaped as `\"` and (CRLF) newlines as `\r\n`

A simple example:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ 
  foo = '{ "bar": 
           "baz" }' 
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output (note how the `foo` property value became a single-line string with `"` and newlines escaped):

```
{
  "foo": "{ \"bar\": \n           \"baz\" }"
}
```

Comment: Ha ok I understand the difference. Thanks, it saved my afternoon haha. When I use [pscustomobject] @{ logins = $user_data } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 it works perfectly and I can send the payload in the correct format :). Best regards

Comment: Glad to hear it, @AndyMcRae.